# CSS and Js not loaded in controller action view

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC when i am move from one controller action view to another through form post the js and css files are not loaded those are added in another controller action view. First Controller view used layout but in second one not
In Second controller action View :

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/ChatStyle.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    --------------large code related to signalR----------------
 });
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     // content
  </body>
 </html>
```

If I am using direct second controller action view through Crtl + F5. then its working fine
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is the 2nd page not using _Layout?

Comment: becoz i dont need that and i want upload upper given javascript code and CSS code when 2nd view render

Comment: Are you sure the relative path you are using `../../` will work? Keep in mind in exact page view it will be relative to your page url, not the view's directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine when I am using all CSS and JS part of view use after the Html content Like :

_chatLayout.cshtml

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->


    </body>
  </html>
```

---

View is :

```
 @{ 
   ViewBag.Title = "Chat window"; 
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_chatLayout.cshtml";
 }
  <div>
    // content
  </div>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/ChatStyle.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
      -----large code related to signalR------
     });
   </script>
```